# Find the Fourier transform of the absolute value of a function, given its Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

It is possible to find the following Fourier transform? $
\widehat{\vert f\vert}(\xi)$, provided $ f $ has Fourier transform. I have not found any information about this statement.

Comment: Nasty things happen if $f$ passes 0 through. You will get jump in first derivative at those points. A jump in first derivative will cause the integral to be discontinous so it is one step worse than ordinary discontinuities which spread like hell.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformHeavisideStepFunction.html you can see the function to convolve with here: the dirac $\delta(k)$ is the nice part. The $\frac{-i}{\pi k}$ is the nasty.

Comment: @mathreadler Jump in first derivative is one step _better_ than  discontinuity of the function itself.  It does not cause any integrals to be discontinuous.

Comment: @FTP yes you are right. One can still estimate the effect on the Fourier transform by calculating those jumps and the corresponding functions to convolve with in Fourier domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, nonlinear transforms do not play well with Fourier transforms. One exception is $|f|^2$: writing it out as $f\bar f$ and observing that 
$$
\widehat{ \bar f}(\xi) = \overline{\hat f(-\xi)}
$$
we get that $\widehat{|f|^2} $ is the convolution of $\hat f$ with $\overline{\hat f(-\xi)}$.

But without the square it's much worse. Consider that when $f$ is smooth (and thus $\hat f$ decays quickly), the absolute value $|f|$ is generally not differentiable (and so its Fourier transform will not decay so quickly anymore). The point being, $|f|$ and $f$ can look very differently on the Fourier transform side.

Since $|f|=f\operatorname{sign}f$, the question becomes: will you be able to find the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{sign} f$, and to convolve it with $\hat f$?  Chances are that the answer is no.